# How can i fix Julia error?

Tags: julia, distributed-computing

I am using Julia version 0.5.2.

```
julia> addprocs(4);
julia> a=rand(8,8);
julia> distribute(a,2)
```

When I try to use this codes,I get the error:

> ERROR: UndefVarError: distribute not defined

How do i must do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use DistributedArrays? Then you need to add the package: `Pkg.add("DistributedArrays"); using DistributedArrays`.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas yes, but i didn't know which package must be add. thank you.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas i add this package but get same error! why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the DistributedArrays.jl package.

```
Pkg.add("DistributedArrays"); using DistributedArrays
```

Comment: i do this , but when run this line: j=distribute(a,2), i get this error: ERROR: MethodError: no method matching distribute(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Int64)

Comment: i use : @everywhere using DistributedArrays too, but the above error appear.

Comment: @Armaa it means there is no method for `distribute(a,2)` where `a` is an `Matrix{Float64}` and `2` is an `Int64`. But there is the method `distribute(::Array)` so `distribute(a)` should work! See: https://github.com/JuliaParallel/DistributedArrays.jl#distributed-arrays *`distribute(a::Array)` converts a local array to a distributed array.*